# How to prevent opening a fragment in navigation drawer if that fragment is already opened

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

How to prevent opening a fragment in navigation drawer if that fragment is already opened. For example I have a Settings fragment in my `Nav` Drawer at first if click on that frag it opens so now again if I click on that it should not open the same fragment twice as this causes a problem while hitting back button.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the position of the fragment in the list that is currently open. For instance, maintain a variable called `mSelectedPosition`, which is initialized to -1 in `onCreate()`. Then the code in your `onItemClick()` in the `DrawerItemClickListener` can be something like

```
if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
    closeDrawer();
    return;
}

mSelectedPosition = position;
// Continue your work here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you should change the new Fragment at the onDrawerClosed() callback. Maintain a member variable like, currentFragmentPosition.

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
{
    super.onDrawerClosed(view);

    if(clickedPosition != currentFragmentPosition)
    {
        // change Fragment
    }
    currentFragmentPosition = clickedPosition;
}
```